# Rubocop JSON: Align the parameters of a method call if they span more than one line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, rubocop, ruby-style-guide

i got a problem with Rubocop in my testing files. At first, this is my code now:

```
should 'should show user' do
  get user_url(@user),
    headers: @header
  assert_response :success
end

should 'should update user' do
  patch user_url(@user),
    params: {
      data: {
        attributes: {
          name: @user.name
        }
      }
    }, headers: @header
  assert_response :success
end
```

And that is the Rubocop error output:

```
test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:34:9: C: Align the parameters of a method call if they span more than one line.
        headers: @header
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:40:9: C: Align the parameters of a method call if they span more than one line.
        params: { ...
        ^^^^^^^^^
```

So I searched in the styleguide for the correct alignment of JSON. I really tried every combination of indenting and new lines, but Rubocop throws every time the same error. Andy by the way, put the whole JSON in one line is also not the solution.
Can anybody explain, how the correct alignment looks like, so that Rubocop is happy with it?

Comment: `headers: @header` isn't JSON, it's a Ruby hash equivalent to `{:headers => @header}` passed as the second parameter to `get`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change it to

```
should 'should show user' do
  get user_url(@user),
      headers: @header
  assert_response :success
end

should 'should update user' do
  patch user_url(@user),
        params: {
          data: {
            attributes: {
              name: @user.name
            }
          }
        },
        headers: @header
  assert_response :success
end
```

Explanation:

As `user_url(@user)` is your first param to get second param `headers: @header` should be aligned with it

Same applies for second place where you have three params